# Java general array Questions

Tags: java, arrays

I need to put some different size machines in the storage

I am thinking so I have an array of machines with a size of 30 present storge
Machine[] machine = new Machine[30];

Machine has a size in the constructor. eg, Machine m1 = new Machine(10);

Every machine have different size, some machine may need size 5, some may need size 10. 
if I insert a size 5 machine into array, it should take the first 5 slots in the array. if I put a machine with size 10 at the third position, it should take slots from 3-13

```
public class JavaApplication23 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static Machine[] machine= new Machine[30]; 


public void findSlot(Machine unit)
{
    int slot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < machine.length; i++)
    {
        if(fit(i,unit)==true)
        {
            System.out.println("slot "+i+" is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The line is full");
        }
    }

}

public boolean fit(int num, Machine machine)
{
    boolean check = true;
    if(machine[num]==null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < machine.getWidth(); i++)
        {
             if(machine[num+i]!=null)
             {
                 check = false;
             }
        }       
    }
    if(check == false)
    {
        System.out.println("machine does not fit");
    }
    return check;

}
    }
```

The first function is looking for the empty slot where machine can fit. For example, if machine has a size of 10. slots 1-5 is taken, 8-10 is taken. I can't use 6-7 because is too small. so the function should tell me put in position 11, because 11-20 is empty

the second function is helping to check if the machine can fit

---

Here is my question. since my array is an array of machine. No matter what size of machine i put in, it will only take one slot. I need an an array with a total size of machines, which one size equal to one slot. so i can put machine into storage one by one and fit.

Comment: You could try repeating the references to each machine.  For example, if a machine of size 4 is occupying slots 3, 4, 5 and 6; then `machines[3], machines[4], machines[5], machines[6]` could all be equal to that machine.  Since Java types are reference types, that can be done without copying the actual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Class GroupOfMachines, with an int and an array of machines and go through this class and add each machine

Comment: Can you be more specific how I should write this class ? I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: @user2334400 He's saying that you should write a new class `GroupOfMachines` that has an `int` that represents the current number of slots occupied and a `Machine[]` that holds the physical machines. However, IMHO, DavidWallace's comment is the best way to approach this.